# Bind document mouseup in ng-mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events, mousedown

I want something to begin on `ng-mousedown` and end on `mouseup`. I also want that something to continue happening while the mouse button remains down if the mouse leaves the element. A pretty common way to implement this in vanilla Javascript is to bind a document `mouseup` event in the element `mousedown` event, [like so](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbLdeL):

HTML:

```
<button onMouseDown='onMouseDown()'>Click Me</button>
<div id="val"></div>
```

JS:

```
function onMouseDown() {
  var el = document.querySelector('#val'),
      changeValue = function() {
        el.innerHTML = 'done!';
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', changeValue);
      };
  
  el.innerHTML = 'waiting for mouseup...';

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', changeValue);
}
```

I am having trouble implementing this behavior in Angular with [jQuery's `one()`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpjVOo), [`angular.element.one`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpjMbV), and [`addEventListener` / `removeEventListener`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLGMr):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>Note that 'done!' is not rendered, despite 'mouseup' being logged to the console</div>
  <button ng-mousedown='changeValue()'>Click Me</button>
  <div>{{value}}</div>   
</div>
```

JS (jQuery's `one()`):

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeValue = function() {
      console.log('mousedown');
      $scope.value = 'waiting for mouseup...';  
      
      $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        console.log('mouseup');
        $scope.value = 'done!';
      });
    }
  });
```

JS (`angular.element.one`):

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeValue = function() {
      console.log('mousedown');
      $scope.value = 'waiting for mouseup...';  
      
      angular.element(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        console.log('mouseup');
        $scope.value = 'done!';
      });
    }
  });
```

JS (`addEventListener` / `removeEventListener`):

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeValue = function() {
      var changeValue = function() {
        console.log('mouseup');
        $scope.value = 'done!';
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', changeValue);
      };
      
      console.log('mousedown');
      $scope.value = 'waiting for mouseup...';  
      
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', changeValue);
    }
  });
```

I also tried leveraging `ng-mouseup` and `ng-mouseleave` [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVKZOO):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>While clicking the button, move the mouse off of the button and release the mouse button. Note that 'done!' is not rendered, despite 'mouseup' being logged to the console</div>
  <button ng-mousedown='mouseDown()' ng-mouseup="mouseUp()" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()">Click Me</button>
  <div>{{value}}</div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mouseDown = function() {
      console.log('mousedown');
      $scope.value = 'waiting for mouseup...';  
    }
    $scope.mouseUp = function() {
      console.log('mouseup');
      $scope.value = 'done!';
    }
    $scope.mouseLeave = function() {
      if ($scope.value && $scope.value.indexOf('waiting') > -1) {
        console.log('mouseleave, binding mouseup'); 
        $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
           $scope.mouseUp();
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

The result is the same. `$scope.mouseUp` is executed, but `'done!'` is never rendered. [This creates additional problems with `$scope.$watch`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJZEXz):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>value never === 'done!' in $scope.$watch</div>
  <button ng-mousedown='changeValue()'>Click Me</button>
  <div>{{value}}</div>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeValue = function() {
      console.log('mousedown');
      $scope.value = 'waiting for mouseup...';  
      
      $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        console.log('mouseup');
        $scope.value = 'done!';
      });
    }
    $scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
      if (value === 'done!') {
        console.log('value set to "done!"'); 
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have no idea why this question has been left without an answer for more than a month.

The main problem here is simple - the code that updates `$scope.value` is executed outside of AngularJS. In order to make your data binding work you should wrap it with `$scope.$apply` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.value = 'done!';                
});
```

Note that `ng-mouseup` works fine, you can see it when mouseup is triggered above the button. But if you move the mouse outside the button `$(document).one('mouseup'..)` event will occur.

Just keep in mind that you must wrap all the external callbacks with `$scope.$apply` (JQuery HTTP callbacks, DOM events binded not with ng-* directives, `setTimeout`, etc.) if you need it to work with AngularJS binding or watchers. But think twice - calling `$scope.$apply` inside another `$scope.$apply` will cause an error.

You can look through the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) or read more [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).